# Iphone SDK - Can I start a file (song) in the ipod feature of the iphone via the SDK?

Tags: iphone

I would like to have a feature in my iphone application that would start playing a file in my ipod section of the iphone.  Does the SDK allow calls to this?  Is there a simple way to start a song from my application other than using the iphones native interface?

Answer (score 6):

No, I think the official iPhone OS 2.0 SDK does not allow this.

Comment: Downvoters: This answer applies to iPhone OS 2.0. Look at the date!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot launch the iPod app from your application.  But you can easily play a song.

Use the [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) from the [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html) Framework.

Ars Technica has a nice article on it, [here](http://arstechnica.com/journals/apple.ars/2008/11/25/iphone-sdk-watch-new-avfoundation-framework).

Comment: No, a song within your app's sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with 3.0 but I will not go further into it due to NDA issues. The information is available on the Developer Site.

Answer (score 1):

Now that it's public, you're looking for MPMediaPickerController and MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Nope you cannot fire off a song from your media library but you can play a song you have embedded in you app or you download from the web here are some examples

[Apple - Example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/oalTouch/)

[AppsAmuck - Example](http://appsamuck.com/day21.html)